# Ruby on Rails function grapher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm looking for a function grapher that I can use in a small Rails application I'm working on for my university. Is there anything out there? If it needs the values (points) is not a problem but it would be better if it just parsed the equation. The functions will be 100% in ruby format (for example `Math.exp(3*x)`)...

Thanks a lot!

Nicolás Hock

Answer (score 1):

What kind of graphs are you looking for?

Matt Aimonetti created http://github.com/mattetti/googlecharts which may help you....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Flotr](http://github.com/pbosetti/flotr)?

Or you could pull the guts out of [Graphinity](http://www.arachnoid.com/ruby/graphinity/)...

Comment: I I'm looking for something like this: http://www.walterzorn.com/grapher/grapher_e.htm   but it would be awesome to have that on rails =P  (but the 3 answers above would ultimately work)